# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php

i have the code im trying to upload data read from two sensors to in arduino to the WAMP server but when running the localhost\project,i get that Warning.THE php file are located in the projects directory.The Connect.php is used when accessing the database.The Connect.php code is the one used mainly for connection here it is,the add.php proccess the POST from arduino.index.php displays the sensor values in a table:

Below is Connect.php

```
****<?php
    function Connection(){
        $server="server";
        $user="user";
        $pass="pass";
        $db="database";

        $connection = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass);
        //$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
        if (!$connection) {
            die('MySQL ERROR: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db($db) or die( 'MySQL ERROR: '. mysql_error() );
        return $connection;
    }
?>****
```

Below is add.php:

```
**<?php
    include("connect.php");

    $link=Connection();
    $temp1=$_POST["temp1"];
    $hum1=$_POST["hum1"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `tempLog` (`temperature`, `humidity`) 
        VALUES ('".$temp1."','".$hum1."')"; 

    mysql_query($query,$link);
    mysql_close($link);
    header("Location: index.php");
?>**
```

lastly index.php:

```
**<?php
    include("connect.php");     

    $link=Connection();
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tempLog` ORDER BY `timeStamp` DESC",$link);
?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Sensor Data</title>
   </head>
<body>
   <h1>Temperature / moisture sensor readings</h1>
   <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;Timestamp&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;Temperature 1&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;Moisture 1&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      <?php 
          if($result!==FALSE){
             while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                printf("<tr><td> &nbsp;%s </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td></tr>", 
                   $row["timeStamp"], $row["temperature"], $row["humidity"]);
             }
             mysql_free_result($result);
             mysql_close();
          }
      ?>
   </table>
</body>
</html>**
```

Comment: Can the address in `$server` actually be resolved by the server? Perhaps try to use the IP instead, if you're getting an issue with the hostname, but make sure the hostname is valid. If the hostname is valid, make sure the DNS settings on the server are correct.

Comment: Is the database server hostname valid?

Answer (score 1):

You're mising [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [mysql_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (It's not the same thing..)

Connection returns a `mysqli_` connection:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass);
```

But you're trying to use it to select db and query via `mysql_`:

```
mysql_select_db($db) or die( 'MySQL ERROR: '. mysql_error() );
```

Also, using the `mysqli_` connection as a link to a `mysql_` query makes no sense:

```
$link=Connection();
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tempLog` ORDER BY `timeStamp` DESC",$link);
```

Please just take a look at the [mysqli docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) and scrape the `mysql_`code. -- Or even better, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)!

Answer (score 0):

Try either using the mysqli_select_db with the correct params like this

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass);
if (!$connection) {
    die('MySQL ERROR: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($connection,$db) or die( 'MySQL ERROR: '. mysql_error() );
return $connection;
```

Or use the `mysqli_connect()` to also select the database by adding it as the 4th parameter, then you can forget the `mysql_select_db()` completely.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db);
if (!$connection) {
    die('MySQL ERROR: ' . mysql_error());
}
```